# How can I save a new column data into laravel pivot table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

**I have this 3 table:**

stations (id,station_name)
products (id,product_name)

***pivot table***

product_station (station_id,product_id, tank_volum)

[image]

**Station Model**

```
public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->withPivot('tank_volume');
    }
```

**Product Model**

```
  public function stations(){
        
   return $this->belongsToMany(Station::class);
    }
```

> I'm trying to create a station with many products and every product
> have it's tank volume but i can't save the tank volume value to
> database:

**product_station table**

[image]

**this is my controller:**

```
public function store(StationsRequest $request)
    {

//        dd($request);

        $input = $request->all();

        if($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file->move('images', $name);

            $photo = Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;

        }

       $station = Station::create($input);

       $station->products()->sync($request->products , false);

        return redirect('/admin/stations');
    }
```

[image]

**Q: How can i Save Tank volume inside product_station table "pivot table" ?**

Comment: that isn't a [pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) it is a [bridge table](http://davidlai101.com/blog/2017/08/03/handling-many-to-many-joins-using-a-bridge-table-part-1/)

Comment: I don't see `tank_volume` variable in your code.

Comment: yes i know i tried a lot but it didn't work

Comment: I mean, is tank_volume some predefined value? There is no `tank_volume` in `store` method. How do you get value of `tank_volume`? Is it from request, where do you find it?

Comment: no it is not predefined the process to create is: add station details, select product and add tank volume to this selected product . . but i don't know how to save the tank volume with author data in the same pivot table

Comment: So there is `$request->input('tank_volume')` variable (is my question)?

Comment: Ya sure there is tank_volume as an input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220823/discussion-between-tpojka-and-shaher11).

Comment: Are you adding one product at a time - is `attach()` an option instead of `sync`?

Comment: i should use sync 
i add multi product to station so i use sync

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539857/laravel-7-attach-pivot-to-table-with-multiple-values/63540974#63540974

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 7 : attach pivot to table with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539857/laravel-7-attach-pivot-to-table-with-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to `sync()` related extra fields :

```
$product_ids = [];
foreach ($station->products as $product) {
    //collect all inserted record IDs
    $product_ids[$product->id] = ['tank_volume' => 'tank_volume_value'];  
}
//if you want to pass new id from new query
//$product_ids['new_created_product->id'] = ['tank_volume' => 'tank_volume_value'];
```

then

```
$station->products()->sync($product_ids);
```

in this case, better use attach() :

```
$station = Station::create(['fields']);
$station->products()->attach([$product->id => ['tank_volume'=>'value']]);
```